# Where does PAYDAY 2 store the music files?

Tags: steam, pc, mods, payday-2

Where, in the PAYDAY 2 bundles is the music? I understand it is probably in the bundles but that won't be a problem because I've already extracted everything using the bundle modder tool. Also, I am aware the songs are split up, but I just would like to know the bundle location for the soundtracks.

Comment: Did you buy a Steam bundle, as in the soundtrack was purchased along with the game? Or are you trying to extract the music straight from the game files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The music is located in the all_{number} bundle files.

Once you have extracted them, you can find the `*.stream` (Wwise files with another extension) files in `soundbanks/streamed/music`.

To extract the files and convert them to Wave Audio files, you can use Ravioli Game Tools, though don't forget to tick "Allow scanning of unknown files", "Create subdirectory for each input file" (if you do batch extractions) and select "Convert sounds to Wave" in Ravioli Extractor.

Know that the folder mentioned above contain every piece of music, even those that are locked behind DLCs.

EDIT: The Alesso Heist works differently from other heists, and its music is in `soundbanks/streamed/music_alesso`.